# Problem based on area of triangle

Tags: geometry

In the figure, E,C and F are the mid points of AB, BD and ED respectively. Prove that: $8\triangle CEF=\triangle ABD$
[image]

From the given,

$ED$ is the median of $\triangle ABD$
So, $\triangle AED=\triangle BED$

Also, by mid point Theorem 
$EC||AD$ and $CF||AB$.

Now, what should I do next?

Comment: Don't worry about congruence and symmetry.  Just areas which are determined by height and base.  FCD = 1/2 CDE because they have the same base but the height of CDE is 1/2 the height of FCD.  CDE= 1/2 EBD because they have the same height but the base of CDE is only half the height of EBD.  And EBD = 1/2 ABD because they have the same base but EBD has only half the height.  So FDC is 1/8 ABD.

Comment: parallel lines are irrelevant.

Comment: Think of $EF$ as the base of $\triangle CEF$. Then $\triangle CED$ has the same height but twice the base, so $\triangle CED$ has twice the area of $\triangle CEF$. Similarly, $\triangle BED$ has twice the area of $\triangle CED$, and $\triangle BAD$ has twice the area of $\triangle BED$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let (area of) $\triangle ECF = x$.

Then $\triangle FCD = \triangle ECF = x$ (same base, same height - I'll just call this SBSH for brevity).

So $\triangle ECD = 2x$ and $\triangle EBC = \triangle ECD = 2x$ (SBSH)

Hence $\triangle EBD = 4x$ and $\triangle AED = \triangle EBD = 4x$ (SBSH)

Therefore $\triangle ABD = 8x = 8\triangle CEF \ \ (QED)$

Answer (score 0):

Well $\triangle$AED=$\frac{1}{2}\triangle ABD$.

So the problem reduces to showing that

$$\triangle CEF = \frac{1}{4} \triangle BED$$

Since F is the midpoint of ED, we have by similarity that:

$$|EB| = 2|FB|$$

in other words:

$$\triangle CFD = \frac{1}{4} \triangle BED$$

Likewise, also by similarity,

$$\triangle BEC = \frac{1}{4} \triangle ABD = \frac{1}{2} \triangle BED$$

Which implies immediately that $\triangle CEF = \frac{1}{4} \triangle BED$, and hence we are done.

Note that the factors of 1/4 come from the scaling of both the base and the height by 1/2 due to similarity, hence the area is scaled by $(1/2)^2 = 1/4$ due to similarity.

The scaling factor of 1/2 for the bases and heights follows from the fact that the relevant line segments are medians and the midpoint theorem and the subsequent similarity.

Answer (score 0):

Area BED = 1/2 Area ABD as BE = 1/2 BA and BD = BD. (so they have the same base but one has only half the height.

Area CED = 1/2 Area BED as CD = 1/2 BD and E = E. (One has half the base but they both have the same height.)

Area CFD = 1/2 CED as CD = CD and DF = 1/2 DE. (So they both have same base but one has half the height.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Here are the eight triangles:

[image]

([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXijZ.jpg))

Answer (score -1):

ED is the median of △(ABD) and therefore △(AED)=△(BED)=1/2 x △(ABD). 
EC is the median of △(BED) and therefore △(EBC)=△(ECD)=1/2 x △(BED). 
CF is the median of △(ECD) and therefore △(CEF)=△(CDF)=1/2 x △(ECD).

From the three equations above △(CEF)=1/8 x △(ABD)
or 8 x △(CEF)=△(ABD)